# Can you square / cube the value of pi and use the degrees radians?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, pi

I was working on a question in the context of integration.

The question had a step where:

$-2 \cos(\pi^3) - (-2\cos(0))$

which simplifies and was left as:

$ -2(\cos(\pi^3) -1)$

or

$2-2\cos(\pi^3)$

If is $\pi$ equal to 180 degrees radians:

Can you cube $\pi$ so that it would be $5832000$ degrees radians, and use it to simplify the $\cos(\pi^3)$ further? Then, is it correct that $\cos(180^3) = 1$?

So, the final answer is $0$?

Comment: Working in degrees, $\cos((180^3)^\circ) \approx 0.26$ which you may have confused with $\cos((180 \times 3)^\circ) = -1$. Visualizing these values with the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) can reveal why this is the case.

Comment: The units for angles are degrees and radians (in one word each).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not how it works. That is like saying $1 = 24$ because $1$ day is $24$ hours. Degrees and radians are two different measurement units for angles. Note that $\pi$ is a number and does not literally equal $180$. But $\pi$ radians does equal $180^{\circ}$. Moreover, $1$ degree is $\dfrac{\pi}{180}$ radians, and $1$ radian is $\dfrac{180}{\pi}$ degrees.

If your integration is correct, then $-2\cos\left(\pi^{3}\right)-\left(-2\cos\left(0\right)\right)$ just simplifies to $2-2\cos\left(\pi^{3}\right)$.